# AngularJS as a replacement to Spring MVC

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc

I am new to Angular and still trying to learn it. I have an application that I am converting from Struts to a newer Framework. I was planning to use the SpringFramework because we are using for other apps, but now I saw Angular and it seems it uses an MVC pattern too.

I know Angular is processing everything on the front-end while with Spring the controllers are executed in the back-end.

So my question can I use Angular MVC instead of Spring MVC for my app? In What scenario it is better to use Angular as an MVC instead of Spring?

Comment: They're not either-or. It's perfectly acceptable to use angularjs for data-binding on the frontend and SpringMVC on your backend.

Comment: That's what I said too. But if I use Angular for the view part (mapping, binding, etc..) All I need is REST services that returns JSON for it, and that does not necessarily have to be written in Spring.

Answer (score 3):

If to quote SO introduction to Angular JS.

> AngularJS is an open-source JavaScript framework. 
>   Its goal is to augment browser-based applications with Model–View–Controller (MVC)
>   capability and reduce the amount of JavaScript needed to make web applications functional. 
>   These type of apps are also known as Single-Page Applications.

First of all, you can't replace Spring MVC with Angular. They both are different frameworks designed to do different jobs. You spring resides on server side on the other hand, Angular is purely client side. Even if you client side is purely on angular, with out any server support you won't be able to fetch any data. Angular is a JavaScript framework.

What you can do is use spring to create RESTful Web service to support data requests and then you can use angular to request data and using the JSON data that you will receive through Spring. Process that data using angular and display it with any view technology.

Answer (score 0):

Angularjs is a front-end framework and Spring MVC is used in the back-end. How do you use one to replace another?